# Alert user to available ToolTip information

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, tooltip

So typically when developing a user interface using **WinForms**, if there is any additional information about a particular control that I would like to share with the user - I will associate text via the [`ToolTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

However, sometimes the user understandably does not realize that there is additional information available about the control.

For example, I have found that users become confused by `TextBox` controls on forms that are `ReadOnly` despite the `BackColor` being set to `Control` by default. Users will begin typing into them and believe something is broken about the application.

I believe that I could circumnavigate this issue with users if I could somehow alert them to `ToolTip` text being available for the `TextBox`. Similar to how the [`ErrorProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class alerts users with the Error Glyph. The user is prompted to inspect the control due to the glyph.

[image]

It seems that the `ToolTip` class doesn't have a way of associating an icon like this to a given control out of the box.

[image]

I'm not against extending the `ToolTip` class myself, but I suspect that I haven't been the first person to encounter this issue. Perhaps there is a better way to alert users to additional information than my current route.

So my questions are:

1. Is there an existing solution that accomplishes this already available?
2. Is there a better way entirely of alerting users to available additional information than visually prompting them like this?

Comment: May be you could checkout [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42050/ToolTip-With-Image-C)

Answer (score 1):

> For example, I have found that users become confused by TextBox controls on forms that are ReadOnly despite the BackColor being set to Control by default.

This is a common issue. Typically, it is recommended to not only set `ReadOnly` to true, but also remove the control border (setting `BorderStyle` to `None`). This gives a much clearer visual hint.

> Is there an existing solution that accomplishes this already available?

I'd say it depends on the issue you face. However, "baloon tips" may be a nice solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511451.aspx

You can activate them using the [`IsBalloon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.isballoon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

> Is there a better way entirely of alerting users to available additional information than visually prompting them like this?

Often there is, it depends on the situation. You should check the [MS UX Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa511258.aspx) (also downloadable as PDF).

Comment: I totally agree on the `BorderStyle` recommendation. I was discussing the issue with another developer whom suggested that I set the `BorderStyle` to `None`. Additionally, I've been setting the `BackColor` of the `TextBox` to the color of the form. It definitely gets the point across in a strong way. I will be checking out the balloon tips solution and guidelines you posted.